# geom_point_interactive issue when passed alongside geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggiraph

I wonder if you can help me.

I often use the splendid `ggiraph`, but have recently encountered an issue where it doesn't seem to work when one of its interactive geoms is paired with another geom (either from `ggiraph` or `ggplot2`). Let me explain with my example below and start with the data.

```
library(ggiraph)
library(tidyverse)
dput(data)

structure(list(moniker = c("OU", "IN", "AI", "HR", "T ", "LA", 
"AJ", "WC", "BE", "NV"), monthly = c(-0.03489, -0.028034, -0.0374, 
-0.0479, -0.032485, -0.0332, -0.045954, -0.048032, -0.0446, -0.027724
), quarterly = c(-0.096452525515629, -0.0642786819909756, -0.12256466734, 
-0.112914230016, -0.121439751549064, -0.12779609, -0.103490246054841, 
-0.152770470354658, -0.12167068725, -0.0993823354535133), yearly = c(-0.107231010977261, 
-0.00722368758143395, -0.088470240158463, -0.0817767947388421, 
-0.136265993838053, -0.0970216743424386, -0.092159717986092, 
-0.174532024103611, -0.131514750319878, -0.0866996056676958)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

In other words, the data looks like this:

```
glimpse(data)

Observations: 10
Variables: 4
$ moniker   <chr> "OU", "IN", "AI", "HR", "T ", "LA", "AJ", "WC", "BE", "NV"
$ monthly   <dbl> -0.034890, -0.028034, -0.037400, -0.047900, -0.032485, -0...
$ quarterly <dbl> -0.09645253, -0.06427868, -0.12256467, -0.11291423, -0.12...
$ yearly    <dbl> -0.107231011, -0.007223688, -0.088470240, -0.081776795, -...
```

When I do things conventionally, all works fine:

```
data %>% 
  gather(key = "timeframe", value = "return", -moniker) %>% 
  mutate(timeframe = as_factor(timeframe)) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = timeframe, 
      y = return
      )
    ) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(w = 0.15, h = 0)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

... generates:

[image]

However, when I try to use `geom_point_interactive` instead of `geom_point`:

```
data %>% 
  gather(key = "timeframe", value = "return", -moniker) %>% 
  mutate(timeframe = as_factor(timeframe)) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = timeframe, 
      y = return,
      tooltip = moniker
      )
    ) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  geom_point_interactive(position = position_jitter(w = 0.15, h = 0)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

... I get the following:

[image]
(Note that I couldn't upload an `svg` file here, but can confirm that the tooltips from the `geom_point_interactive` work fine.) Furthermore, the same behaviour seems to happen if I replace `geom_boxplot` with `geom_boxplot_interactive`.

So ... to get to my question: **Do you know of a way to preserve the tooltips on the points, whilst having a boxplot that looks like it does in the first picture above?**

As always, many thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `geom_boxplot` is inheritng `tooltip = moniker` which means each `moniker` will get its own box, to avoid this move the `tooltip` aesthetic to `geom_point_interactive` like so:

```
my_data %>% 
  gather(key = "timeframe", value = "return", -moniker) %>% 
  mutate(timeframe = as_factor(timeframe)) %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = timeframe, 
      y = return
    )
  ) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_point_interactive(aes(tooltip = moniker), 
                         position = position_jitter(w = 0.15, h = 0))
```